# returning soap envelope missing values

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, generic-collections

I have a Soap WSDL, set up as a Service Reference in my application that points to the .asmx file. I am having problems with my response soap envelop. I have a collection object that when it is created on my receiving code the values are there. As I step through the code to the point where the soap envelop is now a memorystream and about to be sent back to the calling client, the collection is populated. However, one more press of F10 and im back at the calling client with an empty collection.

Here is my WSDL for my classes I am using:

```
     <complexType name="Step">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="tns:APIObject">
        <sequence>
          <element name="StepType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string" />
          <element name="Name" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string" />
          <element name="Description" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string" />
          <element name="Automation" minOccurs="0" type="tns:Automation" />
          <element name="Sequence" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:int" />
          <element name="Activities" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <complexType>
              <sequence>
                <element name="Activity" type="tns:AutomationActivity" minOccurs="0"    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </sequence>
            </complexType>
          </element>
        </sequence>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="StepInstance">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="tns:Step">
        <sequence>
          <element name="StepDefinition" type="tns:Step" minOccurs="0" />
          <element name="AutomationInstance" type="tns:AutomationInstance" minOccurs="0" />
          <element name="ActivityInstances" minOccurs="0">
            <complexType>
              <sequence>
                <element name="ActivityInstance" type="tns:AutomationActivityInstance" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </sequence>
            </complexType>
          </element>
        </sequence>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="AutomationActivity">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="tns:APIObject">
        <sequence>
          <element name="Name" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string" />
          <element name="Description" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string" />
          <element name="IsActive" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:boolean" />
          <element name="Definition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="tns:APIObject" />
          <element name="Automation" minOccurs="0" type="tns:Automation" />
          <element name="Step" minOccurs="0" type="tns:Step" />
          <element name="Sequence" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:int" />
          <element name="ActivityObject" minOccurs="0" type="tns:APIObject" />
        </sequence>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="AutomationActivityInstance">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="tns:AutomationActivity">
        <sequence>
          <element name="ActivityID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
          <element name="AutomationID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string" />
          <element name="SequenceID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:int" />
          <element name="Status" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:int" />
          <element name="StatusLastUpdate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:dateTime" />
          <element name="StatusMessage" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <element name="ActivityDefinition" type="tns:AutomationActivity" minOccurs="0" />
          <element name="AutomationInstance" type="tns:AutomationInstance" minOccurs="0" />
          <element name="StepInstance" type="tns:StepInstance" minOccurs="0" />
          <element name="ScheduledTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:dateTime" />
          <element name="StartTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:dateTime" />
          <element name="CompletedTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:dateTime" />
        </sequence>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
```

Here is the response Envelop before Serialization and converting to MemoryStream

```
    <soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="">   <OverallStatus>MoreDataAvailable</OverallStatus>
<RequestID>0216f0bb-9d4a-455f-8517-5856f2e6f65d</RequestID>
<Results xsi:type="AutomationInstance" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
<CreatedDate>2013-01-11T12:18:20.453</CreatedDate>
<ModifiedDate>2013-01-11T12:18:25.27</ModifiedDate>
<ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
<CustomerKey>0aeb9113-14ac-f480-cb35-efaf4439dd34</CustomerKey>
<IsPlatformObject>true</IsPlatformObject>
<Name></Name>
<Description/>
<InteractionObjectID>7c9a50f8-645d-48f2-a023-9aea4a31e294</InteractionObjectID>
<IsActive>false</IsActive>
<ScheduledTime>2013-01-11T12:01:53.543</ScheduledTime>
<AutomationID>7c9a50f8-645d-48f2-a023-9aea4a31e294</AutomationID>
<StepInstances>
    <StepInstance>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
        <StepDefinition>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <Name />
            <Description />
            <Sequence>0</Sequence>
            <Activities><Activity>
            <PartnerKeyxsi:nil="true"/>
            <PartnerProperties>     
                <Name>PartnerApiObjectTypeId</Name>  <Value>42</Value>  </PartnerProperties>
            <CreatedDate>2013-01-11T12:00:20.767</CreatedDate>
            <ObjectID>9e34164a-5089-4fe3-aee3-33f0a472de6f</ObjectID>
            <CustomerKey>ebf044ef-8266-433f-b424-cc0aeb3735bd</CustomerKey>
            <Name>test</Name>
            <Description />
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            </Activity></Activities>
        </StepDefinition>
    </StepInstance>
</StepInstances>
<StartTime>2013-01-11T12:18:20.447</StartTime>
<CompletedTime>2013-01-11T12:18:25.27</CompletedTime>
</Results>
</RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
```

StepInstances is the collection that is focus on my issue. As you can see it is populated as expected.

Here is the MemoryStream converted back to an envelop

```
    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:wsa=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">    
<soap:Header>                           <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:a470ddfb-e032-4291-90e2-ce8ffb2b6a12</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:4b5f3202-2207-4691-b33c-36f8a8ff799f</wsa:RelatesTo>
<wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
<wsse:Security>     
<wsu:Timestampwsu:Id=\"Timestamp-4464e3e0-c473-45e8-865f-21b8a0134927\">
<wsu:Created>2013-01-16T22:04:18Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2013-01-16T22:09:18Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns=\"">
<OverallStatus>MoreDataAvailable</OverallStatus>
<RequestID>e25b58e1-5ad7-4cf6-862b-429354f92aca</RequestID>
<Results xsi:type=\"AutomationInstance\">
<PartnerKey xsi:nil=\"true\" />
<CreatedDate>2013-01-11T12:18:20.453</CreatedDate>
<ModifiedDate>2013-01-11T12:18:25.27</ModifiedDate>
<ObjectID xsi:nil=\"true\" />
<CustomerKey>0aeb9113-14ac-f480-cb35-efaf4439dd34</CustomerKey>
<IsPlatformObject>true</IsPlatformObject>
<Name></Name>
<Description/>
<InteractionObjectID>7c9a50f8-645d-48f2-a023-9aea4a31e294</InteractionObjectID>
<IsActive>false</IsActive>
<ScheduledTime>2013-01-11T12:01:53.543</ScheduledTime>
<AutomationID>7c9a50f8-645d-48f2-a023-9aea4a31e294</AutomationID>
<StepInstances>
    <StepInstance>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil=\"true\" />
        <ObjectID xsi:nil=\"true\" />
        <StepDefinition>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil=\"true\" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil=\"true\" />
            <Name />
            <Description />
            <Sequence>0</Sequence>
            <Activities><Activity>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil=\"true\" />
            <PartnerProperties>
            <Name>PartnerApiObjectTypeId</Name><Value>42</Value>
            </PartnerProperties>
            <CreatedDate>2013-01-11T12:00:20.767</CreatedDate>
            <ObjectID>9e34164a-5089-4fe3-aee3-33f0a472de6f</ObjectID>
            <CustomerKey>ebf044ef-8266-433f-b424-cc0aeb3735bd</CustomerKey>
            <Name>test</Name>
            <Description/>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive></Activity></Activities>       
            </StepDefinition>
            </StepInstance>
            </StepInstances>
            <StartTime>2013-01-11T12:18:20.447</StartTime>
            <CompletedTime>2013-01-11T12:18:25.27</CompletedTime>
            </Results>
    </RetrieveResponseMsg>
</soap:Body>
```

After it gets into the MemoryStream it is then sent back to the calling client. In which I look at the object and the StepInstances are null.

Also note that the WSDL I posted was a portion, mainly the offending classes. The returning envelop is a bigger class that contain these classes and was too much to post.

But the very last code that I step into from the receiving client the memorystream is populated. The next f10 I hit I am back at my calling client with my object, and collection is null.

Hope this makes sense and someone can shed some light on it. Any more data you need I will try to post.

Also worthy to note is that all I have access to is the .wsdl file, not the actual WCF project or classes.

For configuring my Service Reference: For Collection Type I chose Generic.List, and Dictionary Type I chose Generic.Dictionary.

UPDATE: The APIObject inside the wsdl looks like this

```
    <complexType name="APIObject">
    <sequence>
      <element name="Client" type="tns:ClientID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
      <element name="PartnerKey" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
      <element name="PartnerProperties" type="tns:APIProperty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
      <element name="CreatedDate" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
      <element name="ModifiedDate" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"></element>
      <element name="ID" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
      <element name="ObjectID" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
      <element name="CustomerKey" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
      <element name="Owner" type="tns:Owner" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
      <element name="CorrelationID" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
      <element name="ObjectState" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
      <element name="IsPlatformObject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:boolean" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
```

Update #2: I misspoke about it being WCF, I only have access to the .wsdl file and after compile I point my Service Reference to the .asmx file.

Comment: Does your WSDL contain the info for APIObject?

Comment: What are you doing that involves a memorystream?

Comment: @Slick86 - Yes I updated my code to include it

Comment: @JohnSaunders - our framework converts it to a memorystream before sending it back to the calling client. I haven't went through the code to see exactly what it is doing. But only converted it back into the envelope to see what the values were.

Comment: Why are you converting to a stream? Encryption? Why not just let WCF handle all that for you?

Comment: I agree and had to update my original post above and answers below. This isn't a WCF but I only have access to the .wsdl file to add my definitions, I then compile the wsdl and made a Service Reference into my app pointing to the .asmx file.

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues with various SOAP client applications like you describe, when the original class that is being serialized into the SOAP response is a direct object reference and does not use a Getter/Setter property. So if you are doing something like:

```
[Serializable()]
public List<StepInstance> StepInstances = new List<StepInstance>;

...

[Serializable()]
public class StepInstance {
    public string PartnerKey = "";
    public string ObjectID = "";
}
```

... this sometimes does not seems to work right with some types of clients. Instead, make sure the objects use a public getter/setter method and the problem when the objects should be deserialized on the client appearing to not happen may very well go away. Don't know why this is, but seemed to make a difference on certain types of SOAP clients. So our example from above might look something more like:

```
[Serializable()]
public List<StepInstance> StepInstances { get { return mStepInstances; } { set { mStepInstances = value; } }

private List<StepInstance> mStepInstances = new List<StepInstance>;

...

[Serializable()]
public class StepInstance {
    private string msPartnerKey = "";
    private string msObjectID = "";

    public string PartnerKey { get { return msPartnerKey; } set { msPartnerKey = value; } }
    public string ObjectID { get { return msObjectID; } set { msObjectID = value; } }
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea, however I do not have a class that I can use a getter/setter on. I only added my classes to the .wsdl file and recompiled it for use. I do not have access to actual code.

I believe I posted in my initial post that this is a WCF service. I think I misspoke. I am referencing in my project a .asmx file and added my new definitions (or classes as I see it) inside the .wsdl file and compiled it. I added Service Reference into my project that points to the .asmx file.